# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1 ionic 2 application

Tags: gradle, ionic2

Hi I am trying to build an application handed over to me by another developer. 

**When I do ionic build android 
I get an error:** 
Could not GET              'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom'.

Connect to 192.168.1.1:808 **[/192.168.1.1]** failed: Connection timed out: connect

I think the IP address highlighted in bold is the main problem. 
**My Router Ip address is 192.168.0.1 where can I change this setting so that the gradle files are downloaded properly.**

Comment: I found the file platforms/android/gradle.properties. Also the ip address is actually 192.168.0.10. But I am still unable to get the program running.

Comment: Have you done a `npm install`? Is it working with `ionic serve`?

Comment: I ran npm install, ionic serve works but I need to deploy it to an android mobile. I still get the same error.